# wp_enqueue_media() slows down my WP site

Tags: posts, query

My website's been incredibly slow and I installed the query monitor plugin to learn more about the issues that caused this.

When loading `"New post"` page, the following query takes `7,3662` (seconds?!) to load, and it's colored in red in the plugin so I guess this has something to do with the slow loading process.

Query:

> SELECT ID  FROM ceujk1ky3r_posts  WHERE post_type = 'attachment'  AND
>   post_mime_type LIKE 'audio%'  LIMIT 1

[image: WP media slow]

Comment: Usually there are three slow queries there for large sites: the checks for audio and then video and then the months-dropdown. There's a core trac ticket for this [#31071](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31071), where various workarounds have been suggested, but nothing concrete yet.